# How to delete 1 day old files in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, centos

I seen many examples of deleting n days old files in Linux but none of them working for me. The following are some commands that I used

```
[root@centos dmp]# find . -mtime +1 -exec rm -Rf -- {} \;
[root@centos dmp]# ll
total 3259164
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba   12754944 Jul 11 21:01 GSW-11-07-2016.dmp
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba   12754944 Jul 12 02:30 GSW-12-07-2016.dmp
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba   12754944 Jul 13 02:30 GSW-13-07-2016.dmp
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba 1099702272 Jul 11 21:01 MI-11-07-2016.dmp
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba 1099702272 Jul 12 02:31 MI-12-07-2016.dmp
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba 1099702272 Jul 13 02:30 MI-13-07-2016.dmp
[root@centos dmp]# find . -name "*.dmp*" -ctime +1 -exec rm {} \;
[root@centos dmp]# ll
total 3259164
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba   12754944 Jul 11 21:01 GSW-11-07-2016.dmp
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba   12754944 Jul 12 02:30 GSW-12-07-2016.dmp
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba   12754944 Jul 13 02:30 GSW-13-07-2016.dmp
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba 1099702272 Jul 11 21:01 MI-11-07-2016.dmp
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba 1099702272 Jul 12 02:31 MI-12-07-2016.dmp
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba 1099702272 Jul 13 02:30 MI-13-07-2016.dmp
[root@centos dmp]# echo find . * -type f -mtime +1 -exec rm {} \;
find . GSW-11-07-2016.dmp GSW-12-07-2016.dmp GSW-13-07-2016.dmp MI-11-07-2016.dmp MI-12-07-2016.dmp MI-13-07-2016.dmp -type f -mtime +1 -exec rm {} ;
[root@centos dmp]# find . * -type f -mtime +1 -exec rm {} \;
[root@centos dmp]# ll
total 3259164
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba   12754944 Jul 11 21:01 GSW-11-07-2016.dmp
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba   12754944 Jul 12 02:30 GSW-12-07-2016.dmp
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba   12754944 Jul 13 02:30 GSW-13-07-2016.dmp
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba 1099702272 Jul 11 21:01 MI-11-07-2016.dmp
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba 1099702272 Jul 12 02:31 MI-12-07-2016.dmp
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba 1099702272 Jul 13 02:30 MI-13-07-2016.dmp
[root@centos dmp]# find . * -mtime +1 -exec rm {} \;
[root@centos dmp]# ll
total 3259164
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba   12754944 Jul 11 21:01 GSW-11-07-2016.dmp
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba   12754944 Jul 12 02:30 GSW-12-07-2016.dmp
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba   12754944 Jul 13 02:30 GSW-13-07-2016.dmp
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba 1099702272 Jul 11 21:01 MI-11-07-2016.dmp
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba 1099702272 Jul 12 02:31 MI-12-07-2016.dmp
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba 1099702272 Jul 13 02:30 MI-13-07-2016.dmp
[root@centos dmp]# find . * -type f -mtime +1 -exec rm {} \;
[root@centos dmp]# ll
total 3259164
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba   12754944 Jul 11 21:01 GSW-11-07-2016.dmp
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba   12754944 Jul 12 02:30 GSW-12-07-2016.dmp
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba   12754944 Jul 13 02:30 GSW-13-07-2016.dmp
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba 1099702272 Jul 11 21:01 MI-11-07-2016.dmp
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba 1099702272 Jul 12 02:31 MI-12-07-2016.dmp
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba 1099702272 Jul 13 02:30 MI-13-07-2016.dmp
[root@centos dmp]# find . * -mtime +1 -exec rm -Rf -- {} \;
[root@centos dmp]# ll
total 3259164
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba   12754944 Jul 11 21:01 GSW-11-07-2016.dmp
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba   12754944 Jul 12 02:30 GSW-12-07-2016.dmp
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba   12754944 Jul 13 02:30 GSW-13-07-2016.dmp
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba 1099702272 Jul 11 21:01 MI-11-07-2016.dmp
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba 1099702272 Jul 12 02:31 MI-12-07-2016.dmp
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba 1099702272 Jul 13 02:30 MI-13-07-2016.dmp
[root@centos dmp]# find . -type f -mtime +1 -name '*.dmp' -execdir rm -- {} \;
[root@centos dmp]# ll
total 3259164
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba   12754944 Jul 11 21:01 GSW-11-07-2016.dmp
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba   12754944 Jul 12 02:30 GSW-12-07-2016.dmp
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba   12754944 Jul 13 02:30 GSW-13-07-2016.dmp
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba 1099702272 Jul 11 21:01 MI-11-07-2016.dmp
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba 1099702272 Jul 12 02:31 MI-12-07-2016.dmp
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba 1099702272 Jul 13 02:30 MI-13-07-2016.dmp
[root@centos dmp]# find . -type f -ctime +1 -name '*.dmp' -execdir rm -- {} \;
[root@centos dmp]# ll
total 3259164
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba   12754944 Jul 11 21:01 GSW-11-07-2016.dmp
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba   12754944 Jul 12 02:30 GSW-12-07-2016.dmp
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba   12754944 Jul 13 02:30 GSW-13-07-2016.dmp
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba 1099702272 Jul 11 21:01 MI-11-07-2016.dmp
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba 1099702272 Jul 12 02:31 MI-12-07-2016.dmp
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba 1099702272 Jul 13 02:30 MI-13-07-2016.dmp
[root@centos dmp]# find . -type f -mtime +1 -name '*.dmp' -print0 | xargs -r0 rm --
[root@centos dmp]# ll
total 3259164
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba   12754944 Jul 11 21:01 GSW-11-07-2016.dmp
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba   12754944 Jul 12 02:30 GSW-12-07-2016.dmp
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba   12754944 Jul 13 02:30 GSW-13-07-2016.dmp
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba 1099702272 Jul 11 21:01 MI-11-07-2016.dmp
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba 1099702272 Jul 12 02:31 MI-12-07-2016.dmp
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba 1099702272 Jul 13 02:30 MI-13-07-2016.dmp
```

2) I am also trying to delete old files from ftp remote server and posted my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38309645/linux-script-to-delete-ndays-old-ftp-files

**UPDATE:**
I tried the answer but still no luck

```
[root@centos dmp]# find . -type f -mtime +1 -exec rm -rf {} \;
[root@centos dmp]# ll
total 3259164
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba   12754944 Jul 13 17:16 GSW-13-07-2016.dmp
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba   12754944 Jul 14 02:30 GSW-14-07-2016.dmp
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba   12754944 Jul 15 02:30 GSW-15-07-2016.dmp
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba 1099702272 Jul 13 17:16 MI-13-07-2016.dmp
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba 1099702272 Jul 14 02:30 MI-14-07-2016.dmp
-rw-r----- 1 oracle dba 1099702272 Jul 15 02:30 MI-15-07-2016.dmp
[root@centos dmp]#
```

Please advise how can I fix it. Thanks in anticipation

Comment: Do you see the files listed if you specify `ls` instead of `rm`?

Comment: vote up for `ls` idea instead of `rm`

Comment: *vote up for `ls` idea instead of `rm`*, cool, so what result did you get? Was it expected (you saw the names of files you want to delete)? I just tried `find . -mtime +1 -exec rm -Rf -- {} \;` and it worked fine for me.

Comment: my bad. by mistake i used rm -rf *.dmp and all files deleted. now waiting at least one day to check it again

Comment: Don't put `-rf` as an option, it is not needed and can save your data in case of mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
find . -type f -mtime +1 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Comment: Why `-rf` for deleting files? And if OP is wanting to delete only files, I would add `-type f` to be sure it doesn't remove dirs.

Comment: @Marki555 - I added the `-type` suggestion as I think it would be a good idea.  The OP never mentions anything about recursive and force deletes but the examples show that it is being used, albeit with the `-R`.  So I kept the `-rf` based on what I can glean from the OP's examples.  Thank you.

Comment: However the question title does imply that the OP is interested in files, not directories.

Comment: @EJK - Yes, it does.  I added the `-type` option moments ago in response to comments from @Marki555.  Thank you.

Comment: @tale852150 I updated my question and copy pasted output of your command. You can see its not working.

Comment: Try deleting just one file with `rm -rf` and just `rm`.  Also, run the `alias` command and see if `rm` or `find` is aliased.  Provide your results as part of an update to your question.  Thank you.